# Почему разработчики используют div и span вместо соответствующих html тегов?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Собственно, хотелось бы понять: в чем преимущество использования, к примеру,

```
<div></div>
```

Вместо

```
<button></button>
```

этот элемент легче стилизовать? Но, на сколько я знаю, существуют же возможности сбросить вид элемента?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109017/discussion-on-question-by-konstantin-galiakhmetov---).

Answer (score 0):

В HTML есть такое понятие как "**Семантическая вёрстка**" ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)), она нужна как для взаимодействия пользователя с сайтом, так и для поисковиков, при исследовании сайта.

В принципе, вы можете написать сайт без семантики, но лучше всего это осваивать на равне с HTML тегами.

Comment: Вопрос состоял в том, почему порой предпочитают не семантическую верстку.

Comment: @KonstantinGaliakhmetov, к этому вопросу сложно найти ответ, ибо у каждого "разработчика" он будет свой: не указанно в ТЗ, не знает\умеет использовать, не хочется и т.п.

Comment: Вопрос был о том, существуют ли какие-то объективные причины так делать? Существуют ли случаи, когда объективно проще, удобнее или вообще единственно возможно использовать div, а не button.